# Como conectar um socket através da internet

Tags: java, socket

Comecei recentemente a estudar sockets e sei que para criar um servidor eu uso uma porta e para conectar um cliente eu uso a porta e o ip do servidor na rede local, mas gostaria de conectar um cliente a um servidor através da internet (obviamente em redes diferentes) a dúvida é, qual ip eu devo botar?

```java
    ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket("xxx.xxx.xxx", 1234);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá,

Existem basicamente três possíveis casos de conexão, veja:

**1:** Em testes offline, simulando um servidor na sua própria maquina, você utiliza o IP `127.0.0.1`, o tão famoso localhost. Esse IP faz referência ao próprio computador de execução daquele determinado código.

**2:** No caso de um servidor dentro de uma mesma rede, você pode utilizar o IP local do computador. Esse IP é atribuído pelo roteador quando a maquina se conecta na rede, e seu padrão varia de acordo com cada roteador. O padrão de IPs locais mais comum é: `192.168.1.x`, onde x é o número correspondente ao computador.

**3:** Caso você deseje, de uma maquina acessar outra em qualquer lugar da interne, você precisará saber o IP público (ou seja, IP visível para qualquer pessoa na internet) do seu servidor destino.

O que você está tentando fazer se encaixa no último caso, portanto, o IP que você deve colocar para instanciar o Socket é o IP público do servidor.

Espero ter ajudado, abraço!